software-uninstall tag automatically becomes software-installation
I recently found that if I add software-uninstall tag to any question on Ask Ubuntu, and save it, the tag automatically becomes software-installation.
Other users have noticed it too. See this comment How to remove minecraft from ubuntu 22.04 :

WHY DOES IT KEEP SAYING THE TAG IS 'SOFTWARE INSTALLATION' NO MATTER HOW MANY TIMES I CHANGE IT TO 'UNINSTALL'. i DO DO NOT WANT THIS PROGRAM ON MY COMPUTER. I WANT IT PURGED I DO NOT WANT TO INSTALL IT, I WISH I NEVER INSTALLED IT. DO I NEED TO JUST YANK OUT MY SSD BURN IT AND GO BUY YET ANOTHER ONE?

This tag behavior frustrated the user so much that the comment was all caps, and it may already be deleted because it was all caps.
Please fix it.

(note I retagged this as [tag:support] since [tag:bug] creates actual work for SE staff - they need to look into it and tag it with the appropriate status tag. Since it's not an actual bug, there's not need to add more work for them here)

My bad. I'm really sorry.
Recently, an attempt was made to improve the situation with the plethora of installation-related tags. I can admit to being guilty of excessive tag meddling throughout my tenure as a denizen of Ask Ubuntu...
Artur Meinild has already pointed out the question where the matter was most recently raised on meta (installation-tag-shuffling began in ancient times). Eventually, the action taken was recorded in my comment on BeastOfCaerbannog's answer. Further details can be found in this chat. The logic is in the answer - uninstallation is to be considered a subset of installation. So, this is status by design.

Great work! I think there will be no problems this way.

But as you may have noticed, I didn't update the tag wiki and excerpt as promised in the comment! I have updated the excerpt just now. There is no wiki for the tag as yet. I'm really sorry that I didn't even take two seconds to update the excerpt before. I hope the current excerpt could prevent people from getting upset. But if not, we can undo the synonym.

I had also said that I would do the tag wiki, but I totally forgot about that. Sorry! I further edited the excerpt and added the full tag wiki. They need to be reviewed. If anyone feels like improving them further, they are more than welcome to do so! :)

I've approved the excerpt, so now both seems to be in order.  And thanks Zanna, don't sweat it - you did what was agreed upon, and it's just a matter of tying the loose ends.

It's defined as a tag synonym by Zanna: https://askubuntu.com/tags/synonyms
I think it was discussed at some point, and the consensus was to do these synonyms. Here is the discussion thread: Can we fix this tag or should we just [uninstall]?
In any case, it's not a bug, since the tag synonym is working as intended.
